# Wordpress custom post type column sort query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I have a custom post type called `reservation`. In it I get the reservation for event/room you name it (not important).

When I go to my custom post type page, I get all the posts nicely displayed. The first column is the reservation date. Now the reservation date can be one - `28.11.2015`, but it can also be multiple dates - `28.11.2015, 29.11.2015, 02.12.2015.`

I would like to enable the sorting of that column. The problem is, this is a string, not a number so I cannot just create a simple sortable column query like described [here](http://wpdreamer.com/2014/04/how-to-make-your-wordpress-admin-columns-sortable/).

So far I tried this:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-reservation_sortable_columns', 'reservation_sortable_column' );

if (!function_exists('reservation_sortable_column')) {
    function reservation_sortable_column( $columns ) {
        $columns['reservation_date'] = 'reservation_date';
        return $columns;
    }
}

add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts', 1, 2 );

if (!function_exists('manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts')) {
    function manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts( $pieces, $query ) {
        global $wpdb;
        if ($query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby = $query->get('orderby') ) ) {
            $order = strtoupper( $query->get('order') );
            if ( !in_array( $order, array('ASC', 'DESC') ) ) {
                $order = 'ASC';
                switch ($orderby) {
                    case 'reservation_date':
                        $pieces[ 'join' ] .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wp_rd ON wp_rd.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID AND wp_rd.meta_key = 'reservation_date'";
                        $pieces[ 'orderby' ] = "STR_TO_DATE( wp_rd.meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y' ) $order, " . $pieces[ 'orderby' ];
                        break;
                }
            }
            return $pieces;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because I'm working with strings.

Luckily, my dates (when a person picks them), are already sorted lowest to highest date. They are stored in `$custom['reservation_date']` array, where `$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID)`. So I can get them like `$custom['reservation_date'][0]`.

I can also separate the first date

```
preg_match('/^(.+?),/', $custom['reservation_date'][0], $matches);
```

If it's only one date, without the comma, I can then get them out like:

```
$first_date = (!empty($matches)) ? $matches[0] : $custom['reservation_date'][0];
```

Now what's bothering me is how to use this in my custom query? Currently the sorting is done on `meta_value` `reservation_date` (string). How do I make it so that I can sort based on these first dates?

Say I have dates like:

> 19.11.2015, 20.11.2015
>
> 28.11.2015
>
> 14.11.2015, 15.11.2015
>
> 13.11.2015

When I click to sort them in ascending order I'd like to get

> 13.11.2015
>
> 14.11.2015, 15.11.2015
>
> 19.11.2015, 20.11.2015
>
> 28.11.2015

And another click on the column will order them descending

> 28.11.2015
>
> 19.11.2015, 20.11.2015
>
> 14.11.2015, 15.11.2015
>
> 13.11.2015

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't do that. Datepicker I have (from which I get my dates) stores the entries as a string, not a number. Everything in my plugin is working already, except this.

Comment: I could probably build a custom meta value from which I could sort that would have numbers in it, then I could use `pre_get_posts` solution.

Comment: I just copied that part from the tutorial, my sql knowledge is basically nonexistent :S That's why I asked here for any help and guidance

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but I have everything created and working (front end and back end), and sorting is just a feature I wanted to add (not essential unless client asks). I wouldn't like to mess it all up.

Comment: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ add on to jquery-ui

Comment: Thought it might be;-)

Comment: Your manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts code you have should work proper, as it's well documented in a number of sites...  It uses SQL to convert the string date into a numeric time stamp. Are you getting any error messages or anything?  Or are you getting improper sorting results?  Is it breaking because you might have multiple dates?  In the event of a multiple date, you simply have to extract only the first date in your SQL.

Comment: No errors, but sorting is random. I click to sort, and there is no order. I think that it's breaking because of multiple dates. I have `$first_date` extracted from every date, but I don't know how to implement that in the SQL query (I don't know much about that)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to sort in the WP Query as you have not stored the values in a way WordPress understands.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

You should store dates as **YYYY-mm-dd**.

Either change how the dates are stored or use PHP after the database request to sort.

```
// 1. if you change how "reservation_date" is stored in the db

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'reservation',
    'meta_key' => 'reservation_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

// 2. if you choose to sort with PHP after pulling the data

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'reservation'
));

usort($posts, function ($post_a, $post_b) {
    $post_a_custom = get_post_custom($post_a->ID);
    $post_b_custom = get_post_custom($post_b->ID);

    $post_a_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $post_a_custom['reservation_date'][0]);
    $post_b_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $post_b_custom['reservation_date'][0]);

    if ($post_a_date == $post_b_date) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($post_a_date > $post_b_date) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably convert time with unix when I'll create a final version. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm still working on my plugin, and this will definitely come in handy, I'll mark it as correct and if I'll have any more questions I'll ask :)